# plural adjective ending for "die Sofas"

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number, adjective-ending

What will be the adjective ending for the plural form of nouns that end with this one--> for example: Das Sofa the plural form is "Die Sofas" should i just omit the letter "n" for this word?
 I got confused by the rule of applying the "n" at the end of the word like: "Die netten Kindern".

Comment: Why do you want to add a 'n'? Can you clarify your question? I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: Von welcher Regel redest Du?  "Die netten Kindern" ist auch falsch.

Comment: Yes.I know now that what was stated above was indeed wrong!! Thank you for widening my understanding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't matter which plural form a particular noun uses, the rules about which adjective ending to use don't require this information. So it's for nominative

> das Sofa -> die Sofa**s** -> die nette**n** Sofas
>   das Kind -> die Kind**er** -> die nette**n** Kinder

and for dative

> dem Sofa -> den Sofa**s** -> den nette**n** Sofas
>   dem Kind -> den Kind**ern** -> den nette**n** Kindern

"Die netten Kindern" is wrong, no matter how you look at it.

For a table of adjective endings in strong/weak/mixed inflection, see e.g. [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_adjectives#Strong_inflection).